# Vulkan.hpp Supbass attachment violates validation layer

Tags: c++, graphics, gpu, vulkan

I have the following vulkan initialization code:

```
vk::AttachmentReference color_attachment_ref(0,
    vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal);

auto colorAttachment = *(VkAttachmentDescription*)&color_attachment;
auto colorAttachmentRef = (VkAttachmentReference)color_attachment_ref;

/*vk::SubpassDescription spass({}, vk::PipelineBindPoint::eGraphics, 1,
    &color_attachment_ref);
auto subpass = (VkSubpassDescription) spass;*/
VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentRef;
```

This works perfectly, however, when I try to refactor the code to use the objects in vulkan.hpp instead:

```
vk::AttachmentReference color_attachment_ref(0,
    vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal);

auto colorAttachment = *(VkAttachmentDescription*)&color_attachment;
auto colorAttachmentRef = (VkAttachmentReference)color_attachment_ref;

vk::SubpassDescription spass({}, vk::PipelineBindPoint::eGraphics, 1,
    &color_attachment_ref);
auto subpass = (VkSubpassDescription) spass;
/*VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentRef;*/
```

I get:

```
validation layer: Layout for input attachment is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL but can only be READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL or GENERAL.
UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-InvalidImageLayout
```

As far as I can see, both method initializations are equivalent, what am I screwing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the order of parameters. The parameters I am passing don;t correspond to the function signature, the correct version is:

```
vk::SubpassDescription spass({}, vk::PipelineBindPoint::eGraphics, 0, nullptr, 1,
&color_attachment_ref);
```

To account for 2 unused parameters.